# Visual Basic: Deserializing a Json containing an array fails

Tags: json, exception, basic

I tried to deserialize the following Json:

{
"Compensations":
[
{"Name": "Compensation_01"},
{"Name": "Compensation_02"}
]
}

paste special => paste json as classes results in

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property Compensations() As Compensation
End Class

Public Class Compensation
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

both NewtonSoft:
Dim cmpnstn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(json)
and Microsoft:
Dim cmpnstn = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(json)

throw exceptions:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ...

System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to Path: ... LineNumber: ... BytePositionInLine:

Public Property Compensations() As Compensation result in the IL Code (no array)

```
public Compensation Compensations
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

When I change the property to

Public Property Compensations As Compensation()

I get the IL code for an array

```
public Compensation[] Compensations
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

My question is: Why does that paste special do that form of property declaration
and what is the meaning of that Compensations() As Compensation.

Answer (score 0):

change
Public Property Compensations() As Compensation
to
Public Property Compensations As Compensation()

The latter solves the problem.